# optimization for evaluating multiple regexes

Tags: regex, algorithm, optimization

given a set of regexes, ex: `{r'abc',r'ab[^cd]',r'.bd'}`. is there a way to combine them into a 'regex tree/acyclic directed graph'. for the small example it would look something like:

```
root (r'')  ->: n1, n2;
n1   (r'ab') ->: n3, n4;
n2   (r'.bd' or r'[^a]bd') ->: matched r'.bd'
n3   (r'c') ->: matched r'abc'
n4   (r'd') ->: matched r'.bd'
n5   (r'.' or r'[^cd]') ->: matched r'ab[^cd]'
```

or something similar to this so that partial matches of previous regexes can  be used to evaluate next regexes.

Comment: I don't think Python supports anything like this out of the box, but you may implement this yourself.

Comment: Google "python recursive descent parsing"